# Bluetooth USB device shows up as HID Keyboard. Is it safe?

Tags: windows-10, usb

I bought a USB Bluetooth adapter and my PC now has Bluetooth available, but while it's connected it is makes a "HID Keyboard" show up in my "Mouse, keyboard & pen" setting in Windows (which I can remove until I re-plug it again).

Does it mean the device is also a malicious hidden keyboard? Something like a Rubber Ducky for example?

Comment: What would stop any input device, "HID Keyboard" or not, from being malicious?

Comment: @user nothing I guess but there's a difference between a keyboard from a giant brand and a cheap adapter from AliExpress which to my knowledge isn't a keyboard

Comment: Depending on the chipset that it uses, it might be implementing the "HID proxy" feature, which can have some benefits like allowing the connected devices to work in the BIOS or when the host does not have Bluetooth drivers available.